# Audio recording in QuickTime with Apple Script

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I run AppleScript to perform audio recording in QuickTime Player. How I can wait for a moment when user clicks a button to stop audio recording? We need to replace "delay 5" with waiting.

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.m4a"
delay 1
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set new_recording to (new audio recording)
    tell new_recording
        start
        delay 5
        stop
    end tell
    
    open for access file filePath
    close access file filePath
    export (first document) in filePath using settings preset "Audio Only"
    close (first document) without saving
    ignoring application responses
        quit
    end ignoring
end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd wait for the **User** to manually stop the recording to then proceed and proceed the rest of the *code*:

```applescript
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.m4a"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set newRecording to (new audio recording)
    set docName to name of newRecording
    tell newRecording to start
    repeat while document docName exists
        set clickedCancelButton ¬
            to my checkForSheet1AndClickCancel()
        if clickedCancelButton then ¬
            tell application "QuickTime Player" to ¬
                tell newRecording to stop
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell

open for access file filePath
close access file filePath

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    export (first document) in filePath ¬
        using settings preset "Audio Only"
    close (first document) without saving
    quit
end tell

on checkForSheet1AndClickCancel()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "QuickTime Player"
            if (exists sheet 1 of window 1) then
                click button 2 of sheet 1 of window 1
                return true
            else
                return false
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end checkForSheet1AndClickCancel
```

---

**Notes**:

The `open for access` and `close access` *commands* are part of **Standard Additions** and actually silently error out when wrapped within the `tell application "QuickTime Player"` *block* and why they have been separated. This avoids wasted **CPU** *cycles* having too correct for the silent errors by not having to call them a second time under `tell current application`.

As coded, this assumes there will only be one **QuickTime Player** *window* doing an *audio recording* at a time and remains the frontmost *window* of **QuickTime Player**.

It is also coded so if the **User** clicks the **close** *button* on the `new audio recording` *window* the **Cancel** *button* is clicked and the *script* stops and saves the recording.

Adjust the *value* of the `delay` *command* within the `repeat` *loop* as you feel is appropriate.

This was tested under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region**  set to **English (US)** in **System Preferences** and worked for me as coded.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It almost works, but we found 2 problems:
1. It works for English interface of macOS when we check "Audio Recording" caption. It doesn't work for German or French language.
2. If user click X button to close QuickTime without pressing stop recording button, the app offers to save the audio file and then QuickTime window freezes.

Comment: @Igor, I added code to account for the name of the _window_ of the `new audio recording` and a _handler_ that stops and saves the recording if the User presses the close button on the _window_ of the `new audio recording`. If this doesn't cover your issues then let me know and I'll delete it for good.

Comment: @Igor, Did the update answer work for your needs?

Comment: Thanks again for your generous help! Regrettably the updated script doesn't work correctly on my Mac. On clicking Stop button it saves an empty .m4a audio (0 bytes) and file is always saved on Desktop, even if I set full file path "/Users/mac/Documents/test.m4a"

Comment: @user3579815, To be honest I'd prefer you come up with your own as it is a part my style of answering questions involving coding. That said, I certainly cannot stop you from doing what you want because of the license for the content of a post: [What is the license for the content I post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: Of course, I can come up with my own, likely tweak based on an example from the Internet, which is my plan anyway, wouldn't be right to have an exact copy of somebody elses', but thanks.